# How to restart a systemd service upon resume

Tags: linux, systemd, suspend

I have the following service configuration :

```bash
$ systemctl cat bluetooth
# /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth service
Documentation=man:bluetoothd(8)
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.bluez
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
NotifyAccess=main
#WatchdogSec=10
#Restart=on-failure
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
LimitNPROC=1
#RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=bluetooth.target suspend.target
Alias=dbus-org.bluez.service
```

I added the `suspend.target` in the `WantedBy=` parameter of the `[Install]` section (`man systemd.unit`) for the service to be restarted upon resume but this does not work.

EDIT0 : The service is not stopped at suspend but it needs to be restarted after resume because this service does not support suspend/resume operation on my configuration.

EDIT1 : The `suspend.target` should also work because according to `man systemd.special` :

> ```bash
>    suspend.target
>        A special target unit for suspending the system. This pulls in sleep.target.
> ```

EDIT2 : It seems that the command `sudo systemctl edit --full bluetooth` created another copy of the `bluetooth.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` which became different (from `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`) once the file was saved.

I've just noticed I had two different versions of `bluetooth.service` so I was a little confused.

How to restart a systemd service upon resume ?

Comment: What causes the service to be stopped before suspend/resume?

Comment: @user1686 Added EDIT0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Create the new systemd service:

  ```
  sudo vim.tiny /lib/systemd/system/blrestart.service
  sudo ln -s /lib/systemd/system/blrestart.service /etc/systemd/system/
  ```

  Paste the next to it:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Restart Bluetooth after resume
  After=suspend.target

  [Service]
  Type=simple
  ExecStart=/bin/systemctl --no-block restart bluetooth.service
  # ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl --no-block restart bluetooth.service

  [Install]
  WantedBy=suspend.target
  ```
- Enable and start the newly created service:

  ```
  sudo systemctl enable blrestart && sudo systemctl start blrestart
  ```

Comment: Here's what I get after resuming the computer `blrestart.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC`

Comment: Ok. I tested it on sshd.service, because of I don't have bluetooth adapter here. Service becomes active only after resume to restart another service.

Comment: On my system, `systemclt` is inside `/bin/` not `/usr/bin/`. Now it work fine, pb. solved. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d` [creating your scripts there](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=144901):

```
# 70yourservice
case $1 in
    hibernate)
        echo "Hey guy, we are going to suspend to disk!"
        ;;
    suspend)
        echo "Oh, this time we are doing a suspend to RAM. Cool!"
        ;;
    thaw)
        echo "Oh, suspend to disk is over, we are resuming..."
        ;;
    resume)
        systemctl restart yourservice.service
        ;;
    *)  echo "Somebody is calling me totally wrong."
        ;;
esac
```

Don't forget `sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/70yourservice`

Comment: Added EDIT1. According to the manual, `suspend.target` pulls in `sleep.target`. I don't understand why this does not work.

Comment: Not yet because I was a little confused. Please read my EDIT2 to understand why.

Comment: I just tried the `Restart=always` but it didn't succeed.

Comment: I also just tried with a new script in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/` but it only works if I suspend via the `sudo pm-suspend` command.

Comment: What about the `After=` parameter ?

Comment: I tried the `After=suspend.target`and `WantedBy=bluetooth.target suspend.target` parameters but the system still does not restart the bluetooth service upon resume.