# Restart service after resume only if it was active

Tags: systemd

I need to restart a faulty openvpn service which gets screwed by suspend/resume. My idea is to create a dedicated restart service as documented in many places (e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1528786/how-to-restart-a-systemd-service-upon-resume)), but I want the restart to happen only if the service was actually active at the moment of suspending, since I don't always use the VPN and I don't want it to be silently brought up by the resume procedure. I didn't find any clear indication about this use case, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question: `systemct try-restart`. From `man systemctl`:

```
 try-restart PATTERN...
           Stop and then start one or more units specified on the command line if the units are running. This does nothing if units are not running.
```